# Handle blur event of 'container' without assigning click and focus events to EVERYTHING

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

While I do have a specific problem, I'm interested in whether there actually IS a solution other than my example below.

I want to hide an element (div etc.) when a user loses focus away from it.

I've played with `onBlur` and `onFocusOut` (which seems like it COULD do the job with `event.relatedTarget`, but Firefox support is limited).

Many times I have had to do something like (pseudo jQuery);

```
$('*').on('focus,click', function() {
    // If this is not a descendant of .toolbar
       // run .toolbar faux blur event
});
```

But I really really don't like having to set focus and click events on every single element in the document.

Also this probably does not account for if the user minimises their browser window etc. so would have to also have a `window.onBlur` and push the "faux blur" functions to all elements.

I'm looking for a "nice" way to do this, ideally without having to add event listeners to every element.

NB; Vanilla JavaScript code preferred (no jQuery)

Here's a jsbin I'm playing with to show that if you go from an input and click onto a text node you can't tell if it's within the container element or not. http://jsbin.com/hogot/6/edit

Comment: You should tag this as jquery first off. Second have you heard of event delegation?

Comment: I'm not actually using jQuery, would prefer not to, and actually at the bottom I state that Vanilla Javascript is preferred. jQuery was there simply there to make the example code shorter.

Comment: Gotcha. Your best bet will still probably be event delegation. Which way of implementing it is up to you.

Comment: My thoughts were to do that and use relatedTarget, however I'm unsure how reliable relatedTarget is. If you just click on a text node, you get 'null' as the relatedTarget, so I cannot check to see if it's within the current element or not.

Comment: Do you mean using blur?

Comment: Yeah, using blur. Here's an example of what I mean; http://jsbin.com/hogot/6/edit I want anything inside the toolbar to not count as blur, anything outside to count as blur.

Answer (score 1):

You can use event capturing.

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html

JsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/60eL4nws/5/

HTML

```
<form>
    <input name="first_name" type="text" />
    <input name="first_name" type="text" />
    <input name="first_name" type="text" />
    <input name="first_name" type="text" />
    <input name="first_name" type="text" />
    <input name="first_name" type="text" />
    <input name="first_name" type="text" />
    <input name="first_name" type="text" />
    <input name="first_name" type="text" />
    <input name="first_name" type="text" />
    <input name="first_name" type="text" />
    <input name="first_name" type="text" />
    <input name="first_name" type="text" />
</form>
```

JS

```
function handler(event) {
    console.log(event);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    // Firefox    
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox')>=0) {    
        document.body.addEventListener('blur', handler, true);

    // Opera, Safari/Chrome
    } else if (document.body.addEventListener) {
        document.body.addEventListener('DOMFocusOut', handler, true)

    // IE
    } else {
        document.body.onfocusout = handler
    }

});
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question exactly. I'm trying to detect blur from a div (which may contain some inputs), onto any other element, text node (click, focus on another input, move to another window, e.t.c.)

Comment: This will capture any blur event on the page at any level in the DOM tree, it even captures when a div blurs. - http://jsfiddle.net/60eL4nws/6/

Comment: Yep, but I can't see how you can go from inside an input, and just click on the document body, or a paragraph somewhere, and know that you've not clicked inside the 'container' div you are listening for.

Comment: The listener captures *any* element blurring on *any* level. Check out console log to confirm. If you just attach the listener to document.body then it will capture all blur events that happen in the page for all elements.

Comment: None of these work for me. I have to either put an "onblur" attribute directly on the body tag, or call "window.addEventListener('blur', handler, true)". document.body.addEventListener for blur just does not work.